# В чем будет разница метода synchronize()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вот такой не сложный кусок кода

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter1 = new Counter();
        Counter counter2 = new Counter();
        Counter counter3 = new Counter();
        Counter counter4 = new Counter();

        counter1.start();
        counter2.start();
        counter3.start();
        counter4.start();

        counter1.join();
        counter2.join();
        counter3.join();
        counter4.join();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (values[i] != 1) {
                System.out.println("Массив values содержит элементы неравные 1");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer count = 0;
    public static int[] values = new int[105];

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 105; i++) {
            values[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public synchronized static void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }

    public synchronized static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public static class Counter extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {

    ---->>> synchronized (Counter.class) {  <<<---
                    incrementCount();
                    values[getCount()]++;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } while (getCount() < 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так когда пишу `synchronized (Counter.class)` показывает правильно когда было вот так `synchronized (this)` говорило, что не правильно...

В чем разница? Я понимаю, что параметр это локер , но какая разница какой локер будет передан в данном примере? Считает то он одно и тоже ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`synchronized (this)` – это блокировка на уровне объекта (**конкретного экземпляра** класса).

`synchronized (Counter.class)` – это блокировка на уровне класса (на уровне **всех существующих экземпляров** данного класса).

Пусть два потока работают с **разными** инстансами, тогда:

- в блоке `synchronized (this)` могут одновременно работать оба потока;
- в блоке `synchronized (Counter.class)` может работать только один поток, второй будет ждать выхода первого из этого блока.

Давайте рассмотрим конкретный пример:

Вариант номер один:

```
class Example {

    void print() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": i = " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вариант номер два:

```
class Example {

    void print() {
        synchronized (Example.class) {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": i = " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Создание и запуск потоков:

```
Example example1 = new Example();
Example example2 = new Example();

Thread t1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        example1.print();
    }
};

t1.setName("First thread");
t1.start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        example2.print();
    }
};

t2.setName("Second thread");
t2.start();
```

В первом варианте мы получим:

```
Second thread: i = 0
First thread: i = 0
Second thread: i = 1
Second thread: i = 2
First thread: i = 1
First thread: i = 2
```

А во втором:

```
First thread: i = 0
First thread: i = 1
First thread: i = 2
Second thread: i = 0
Second thread: i = 1
Second thread: i = 2
```

Как видно из результатов, в первом случае потоки выполняются асинхронно, а во втором случае, один поток ждет пока другой поток выйдет из синхронизированного блока.

Comment: В первом случае как видно выполнение асинхронное и я так понял, что синхронное выполнение будет в случае если мы 2 раза запустим выполнение одно и того же обьекта (допустим `example1`) ? Верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Да. Если два потока будут манипулировать одним инстансом, то в синхронизированный блок они будут заходить по очереди.

Comment: Спасибо! Понял.

Comment: А вот опять тут вопрос у меня) Зачем нам указывать метод `synchronized` в классе `Counter` который покрывает `incrementCount(); values[getCount()]++;` если эти методы изначально уже отмечены как `synchronized`?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, А вдруг метод `incrementCount()` будет вызван откуда-то из другого места?

Comment: Так нет то, что `synchronized` нужно поставить на `incrementCount(); values[getCount()]++;` это понятно, вопрос в том, зачем ставить `synchronized` в классе `Counter` ? Один раз ставим `synchronized` на эти методы `incrementCount(); values[getCount()]++;` и все...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Затем, что `synchronized` в методе – это блокировка на уровне **объекта**, а требуется блокировка на уровне **класса**.

Comment: аа)) вот оно что) я то думал что когда мы ставим `synchronized` при объявлении метода класса, то это считается блокировка на уровне класса, а не обьекта)

Answer (score 0):

Ну тогда, когда вы синхронизируете по классу, то по сути в одно время может исполняться только один такой блок кода, не зависимо от того в каком экземпляре объекта. А когда синхронизируете по `this`, то синхронизируется по данному экземпляру, т.е. синхронизация данного счетчика никак не влияет на другие, поэтому они будут выполняться, а не ждать завершения выполнения друг друга.